# ROC and constant factor on probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, roc

I play around with a few data to learn and I am wondering about something;
I can evaluate my results with ROC which is processed from FP and FN.

I had predicted a few probabilities for my events to appear. it gave a ROC compared to original probability.
I then multiplied all of these probabilities par various factors, close enough to 1.
It gave absolutely the same ROC (at 8 digits past 0).

Is it normal, or does it indicate something about my data?
Could I, playing with factors, be able to find back the original values of probability for my event? (just a theoretical question, it's no prediction so it's not interesting from a ML point of view, but I want to be sure to understand better).

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ROC curves are based on the *ranking* produced by your model, that is the ordering of your test set based on the decision values produced by your model (cfr. [Section 2.1 in my paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.06837.pdf) for a more detailed description).

Hence, ROC curves are insensitive to any order-preserving transformations on decision values (such as your probabilities). As scaling does not change the order of decision values, you end up with exactly the same curve.

Generally, you can apply any strictly monotonically increasing function $f$ on your decision values and end up with exactly the same ROC curve, that is any function $f$ for which $f(a) > f(b)$ if $a > b$.

Finally, note that ROC curves can also be used for non-probabilistic models, such as support vector machines. This is one of the reasons they are so popular.

Comment: I understand better, thanks. Just to be sure and clarify, actually the ranking is what produce the number of FP and FN. So why is it insensitive? I mean, if you have 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, for p=0.3 you will have a different number of events assumed as verifying the hypothesis than with double of each of these. Is it because the function is continuous, so it somewhat "balance" over the span of the 0,1 interval?

Comment: Every decision value threshold $\tau$ is associated to a single contingency table, which is a single point in ROC space (i.e., a TPR-FPR pair). When you multiply decision values by a factor $\alpha > 0$, you are modifying the threshold $\tau_2 = \alpha \tau_1$ that is associated to that specific contingency table (point in ROC space), but not the contingency table itself (i.e., the location of the point in ROC space is unchanged).

Comment: Please upvote this quick, accurate and exhaustive answer^^ I can't but I would. I will read your paper with interest.

Comment: Does this still apply to multi-class situations? E.g. if my model outputs some real-valued scores, a Softmax function applied to them will preserve the order. However, in practice the one-vs-all AUC scores change dramatically after Softmax. How would you explain that?